# SSMS - Changing keyboard shortcut for comment selection

Tags: sql-server, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, ssms

So I wanted to change the keyboard shortcut that's assigned to "Comment Selection" to something that makes sense for me. I don't use many keyboard shortcuts, mainly because I have a hard time remembering all of them.

So, I wanted to change the one that is assigned to "Comment Selection". The default is Ctrl + K, Ctrl + C. I don't like the concept of having to do "2" keystroke combinations to accomplish this. I want to be able to quickly hightlight, enter the keystroke, and then move on, all while leaving one hand on mouse, and one on keyboard.

Too much info...
I changed my keystroke to be Ctrl + Shift + C, but the "event" never fires. It shows up in the options "Edit.CommentSelection" just fine. I overwrote the previous 3 values ("global", "text editor", "data warehouse designer"). I see there are other events that fire when Ctrl + Shift combination is used, so that rules out the possibility of not being able to use the Shift key, which was my original thought.

Any other suggestions on how to get this working for me?

Comment: Not really sure how that changes it much to be honest. You can just hold down control and then hit K + C to comment. Either way it is 3 keystrokes. I try to memorize as many shortcuts as I can so I don't need to ever put a hand on my mouse. :D

Comment: I guess for my change, it's 1 hand vs 2...

Comment: When I go to add that as a shortcut, it says that it's already in use for Edit.CopywithHeaders. Is that the case with you as well? If so, it may be that that event is firing instead of commenting. Try disassociating that shortcut from CopywithHeaders and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Good point, mine was/is assigned to that as well, maybe I didn't un-assign correctly, I'll check it out.

Comment: @BenThul You're right, add that as the "answer" so I can give you credit. BONUS question: how to have the same keystroke shortcut UN-COMMENT at the same time...or is that even possible?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to have one keyboard shortcut do it all (at least out of the box). In essence you'd need a command like Edit.ToggleComment, which doesn't seem to exist. I do see that one of the add-ins that I have installed locally (SSMSBoost) *does* have such a command, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the discussion above, it seems that the shortcut was already assigned to Edit.CopywithHeaders (which is the default assignment for that shortcut). Removing that assignment will fix your problem.